# How do I get html response from axios?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, axios, html-parsing

I want to run some html parsing on a page.I want to know if I can get the whole html page source code as a response. I think I will be using node-html-parser npm package.
I want my axios response in the 2 line after parse.(2nd image.)
To be more specific I want to parse this website
https://mojapp.in/@shiviverma6263
to get the follower count of a user.
Axios is giving me errors.

I want something Like when postman gives the html of that website if i just run a simple get request to that page.

```
axios.get('https://mojapp.in/@piyanka_mongia', {
    params: {

    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
   
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

[postman][1]

````
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';

const root = parse('<ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>');

console.log(root.firstChild.structure);
// ul#list
//   li
//     #text

console.log(root.querySelector('#list'));
// { tagName: 'ul',
//   rawAttrs: 'id="list"',
//   childNodes:
//    [ { tagName: 'li',
//        rawAttrs: '',
//        childNodes: [Object],
//        classNames: [] } ],
//   id: 'list',
//   classNames: [] }
console.log(root.toString());
// <ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>
root.set_content('<li>Hello World</li>');
root.toString();    // <li>Hello World</li>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDAyR.png
````

Comment: What's the error that you're getting from axios?

Comment: @AbirTaheer CORS error.I tried with the CORS headers and its still not working.But postman can show the same webpage html easily without any other headers.I need something like that.Forget this website.How do you get the  html of any website to data scrap??

Comment: is your code running on the server or in a browser environment?

Comment: @AbirTaheer the axios is in the client side.The server isnt implemented yet.

Comment: Use selenium. many websites these days are not rendered server side so you will be way better off using software that mimics a real user visiting a website.

Comment: There's no way for you to bypass the cors restriction since mojapp.in does not include a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response so the browser will always restrict access to it from the client. This restriction doesn't apply if you're fetching from the server so you either need to make the axios call on your server or use some proxy that will let you fetch the content and allow cross origin requests